# Why were there two words for love in Proto-Indo-European?

Tags: etymology, roots

I did some research on the root of the English word 'love' and the French word 'amour' to attempt to find the roots of them. The farthest I can find back is two Proto-Indo-European words, "Lewb" meaning both to love and to cut off, and "Am" relating to the nurturing love between a mother and a baby (this may be wrong though- this is just what I've found). So is there any reason there were two words in this language for love? Is there a difference or is it simply two words that formed?

Comment: But, is Proto-Indo-European English?

Comment: No one sat down and designed these languages. You could ask equally why English only has one word, or greek has multiple (agape, eros philia, ludus, etc etc) or why Arabic has many words for different kinds of horse but no single word for the entire group 'horse'.

Comment: This question is both off topic here and unlikely to find a satisfying answer elsewhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Proto-Indo-European is not English.

Comment: The [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Amy?ref=etymonline_crossreference) says that the root *\*ama* means "to take, hold," not "the nurturing love between a mother and a baby."

Comment: Why the close vote? See the tags. This Q is about etymology. No one said PIE is English.

Comment: I think we need more of such inquisitive Qs here on ELU.

Comment: @TannerSwett: Etymonline isn't a high quality resource: It is compiled by an anonymous historian and it does not give sources. Even https://en.wiktionary.org ist better than that

Comment: @jkReinstateMonica I don't think there's anything anonymous about Douglas Harper, but I admit that he's not a recognized expert and his pages don't cite individual sources.

Comment: Ger *laben* means ca. *to nurture* (self reflexive).

Comment: I think this is on-topic here. "Why" questions may rarely have answers, and when it comes to Proto-Indo-European, you can make that *very* rarely, but that doesn't mean they necessarily don't... and also, a valid answer to a objectively-answerable "why" question is simply that we don't know at this time.

Comment: Why shouldn't there be?

Comment: @Tanner Swett: The name Douglas Harper is not identified in the visible part of etymonline.com, although the self-description might be evident when you know him, and there are some hints in the HTML source code.

Answer (score 9):

It should be noted, anything about Proto-Indo-European is purely hypothetical, based on comparing all its different descendants. That is, there are no Proto-Indo-European people we can go up to and interview about "what is the difference between *this* word and *that* word, exactly?", and there are no written inscriptions talking about a particular word and how it's used.

What we do have are texts in descendant languages that we can compare, that let us know that Latin *amō* and Ancient Greek *philéō* and Hittite *āssiya-* and English "love" all mean roughly the same thing. But those all look very different, and don't point toward a single ancestor to all of them.

So, what does this tell us about Proto-Indo-European? Honestly, not much. Words get replaced over time for all sorts of reasons, and meanings shift, and new meanings arise and old ones die out. There's a pretty clear Proto-Indo-European root for "horse", but English "horse", Spanish *caballo*, and so on are completely unrelated to it due to changes over time: "horse", for example, goes back to a PIE root reconstructed as meaning "vehicle". Greek *philéō* probably comes from an earlier word meaning "friendly", while Hittite *āssiya-* probably comes from an earlier word meaning "good", and Latin *amō* probably comes from an earlier word meaning "mother", and so on.

Even in terms of living languages, the existence of multiple words for a concept isn't unusual. Why does English have separate words "love", "affection", "crush", "romance", "liking", and so on? It doesn't necessarily tell us anything deep and meaningful about English or English-speakers; these are just distinctions that have arisen more or less by chance, and been useful enough to stick around.

Comment: This answer is literally full of love.

Comment: PIE crsos actually meant "runner"

Comment: @Anixx I know it's from *ḱ-rs-, but don't all the non-Germanic descendants mean "vehicle" (e.g. Lat. _currus_)? Seems easier to assume a shift to "vehicle" in PIE than to assume it developed the same way in all the others.

Comment: @Draconis courier, current, epikouros have nothing to do with vehicles.

Comment: @Anixx Those all come from *ḱ-rs-, but surely not from *ḱṛsos? "Current" is from a straight verbal descendant, for example.